# Excel VBA shorten If statement code for automation

Tags: excel, vba

I'm automating an excel form and my code is too long. How do I make my code efficient?

[image]

I haven't tried anything yet.

```
If list = Range("E2").Value Then Result = "321"

If list = Range("E3").Value Then Result = "322"

If list = Range("E4").Value Then Result = "325"

If list = Range("E5").Value Then Result = "404"
```

I expect the output will be short and easy to understand.

Comment: You could use `Select Case` but I don't think that is really addressing the problem.  What is it that your code is trying to do as it looks inefficient?  Why are some of the values cells on a worksheet and others hardcoded?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spreadsheet VLOOKUP: Search in second column and return first](https://superuser.com/q/480338/52365)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly and list is one of the value in the column "E" and you need the corresponding value from the Column "D":

```
Dim a As Range 
Set a = Range("E1:E100").Find(What:=list, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
        If Not a Is Nothing Then
            Result = a.Offset(0, -1).Value
        End If
```

You can use this code to get the list from the column E and then use offset -1 to reach the corresponding value from the Column D